# Using cherry-pick instead of rebase to avoid conflicts

Tags: git

Given a git situation like this:

```
A---B---X---C'---Y (main)
     \
      C---D---E (my-branch)
```

I want

```
A---B---X---C'---Y---D'---E' (my-branch)
```

Note that main has C' which is the same commit as C, but rebased onto X (possibly with some fixups)

99% of the time I can just type `git rebase main` from my-branch and it works great, telling me it noticed that C has already been applied and that it skipped the commit.

But sometimes it has conflicts reapplying C so instead of fixing them I proceed with:

```
git rebase --abort
git checkout main
git branch -D my-branch
git branch my-branch
git cherry-pick C..E
git push -u origin my-branch --force-with-lease
```

And it works with fewer conflicts.   However, it's 5 commands instead of 1, requires deleting a branch, requires hunting down git SHA's and requires a force push.    It has a significant potential for screwing up my branch.

Is there a better way to do this that is less error prone?

Comment: `git rebase` is just automating a series of cherry-picks under the hood. Both courses of action should give similar results. Could you double-check your tests and give an example of a conflict happening in only one case?

Comment: Is the `C..E` intended, or did you mean `B..E` or `main..E`? The difference is that `C..E` would not cherry-pick commit `C`. If it is intentional, then it could explain your observation, but it would also mean that your cherry-pick procedure produces an incorrect result.

Comment: C..E is deliberate.   main already has C', and somebody else has already fixed up some conflicts I can piggy back on.

Comment: I edited the question to make this clear.  Thanks @j6t.

Comment: Use the `-i` option to rebase and delete C from the list. Or if you want it all on the command line `git rebase --onto main C`

Comment: I tried rebase --onto a previous time I had the problem and it didn't work, probably PBKAC.   But "-i" is obvious in hindsight.   Turn it into an answer I'll upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Being on `my-branch` you can do it like that:

```
git reset --hard main
git cherry-pick D^..E
```

Comment: I verified this answer, it works.   Would be accepted but I prefer the comment from @Raymond Chen.   Too bad I can't accept more than one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this that is less error prone?

The most straight forward way to do this is to use the three argument `--onto` version of rebase which will do exactly what you ask for with one command:

```bash
# == Before ==
# A---B---X---C'---Y (main)
#      \
#       C---D---E (my-branch)

git rebase --onto main C my-branch

# == After ==
# A---B---X---C'---Y (main)---D'---E' (my-branch)
```

This will rebase `my-branch` from *but not including* commit C and put on top of `main`.

Comment: If you run `git rebase main` (which you should not do, you should [exclusively use the explicit 2 (or 3) argument form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75113010/23118) e.g. `git rebase main my-branch`), that is basically the same as `git rebase --onto main B my-branch`.