# Rebase feature branch to end of development branch

Tags: git

I'm confused about how I should update a feature branch against a development branch. I have an old feature branch which was created from development as follows

```
development       A--B--C--F--G--H--I
                         \
feature                   D--E
```

I would like to get to the following point, where the feature branch is shown at the end of the git history. I can then merge into development and be happy.

```
development       A--B--C--F--G--H--I
                                     \
feature                               D--E
```

When I do `git rebase development` I get the following, and merge conflicts when I try to merge into master. So I'm not really sure how I should move commit D(feature branch) to be attached to commit I(development branch)

```
development       A--B--C--F--G--H--I
                         \
feature                   D--E--F--G--H--I
```

Comment: You mean you tried `git rebase development` ?

Comment: @Paolo yes I updated

Comment: Read the first example in `man git-rebase` and take note of what the assumed current (checked out) branch is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your local copy of the development branch is up to date by running the following command :

```
git checkout development
git pull
```

Switch back to your feature branch using the following command :

```
git checkout feature-branch
```

Perform the rebase using the following command :

```
git rebase development
```

Once all conflicts have been resolved, use the following command to update the feature branch with the changes from the development branch:

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

merge the feature branch into the development branch:

```
git checkout development
git merge feature-branch
```

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend that you NEVER run rebase with anything less that two arguments ([I don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75113010/23118)). That way there is much less chance of errors.

For the scenario you describe the command to achive what you want (rebase `feature` on top of `development`) then the command to run is

```bash
git rebase development feature   # E.g. rebase feature on top of development
```

This command is independent on which branch that is the current branch (i.e. zero chanche of making a mistake because the current branch was something other than what you assumed), and it is also very explicit and descriptive.

---

Another benefit is that if you wanted to rebase something other than the tip of a branch, then the syntax is exactly the same, you only change the commit.

Let's say commit `I` updates a dependency/framework or something else that you do not want to update to yet but you want to take in all the other commits, e.g. you want to have

```
development       A--B--C--F--G--H--I
                                  \
feature                            D--E
```

Then the rebase command is simply

```bash
git rebase commit_H feature
```

Notice that this "special" case now becomes non-special because you consistently always run rebase with two arguments.

---

If I were the git maintainer I would seriously consider deprecating specifying just one argument to rebase. I think it is really bad.