# How to fix "this branch is 1 commit behind of master branch"

Tags: git, github, branch, git-merge

I am working on android studio and am fairly new to GitHub. I created a new branch diverging from origin/master lets name it "newCommits", I added a new functionality and made 1 commit to this branch and pushed it. Now at Github browser I created a PR and after reviewing the code I merged it in master branch.

A new message popped at the top of newCommits that "This branch is 1 commit behind the master branch."
I know this is due to the extra merge commit, but is there any fix to it?

Every other thread gave the answer to clone the repo and then fetch and push the origin but do I have to do it every time I commit in the newCommits?

I tried Github Desktop:

- Tried to directly merge and then push to origin, worked but no use of PR
- Tried to Rebase but was not successful

[Tried to Merge the newCommits within the Master through Github Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj4xV.png)

Comment: `Every other thread gave the answer to clone the repo and then fetch and push the origin but do I have to do it every time I commit in the newCommits?` Absolutely not. Anyone that suggests that clearly does not understand git.

Comment: Unless `newCommits` is a special branch, after merging it into `master` you can just delete it. Next time you wish to work on more features create a different feature branch from `master` and name it whatever makes sense for that feature. If you want to keep the same branch name for some reason, you can reset it to be on the same commit as `master`, or you can rebase it onto the latest `master`, or you can merge in `master`. All will have the same effect if you have no new unmerged commits on your branch.

Comment: With regards to your branch being one commit behind, I have [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) that goes into detail what that means, I think you will find some useful information there to better understand what is going on. Speaking of which I sense that using Github Desktop hides too much and prevents you from learning git properly, so I strongly suggest you to use the command line exclusively until you are fully confident so that then using a gui app is just a convenience thing.

Comment: It's weird that `newCommits` gives this message about `master` unless it is tracking master. Is it? There is no reason for for it to, but `git branch -vv` will show you

Answer (score 1):

So what has happened here is the following

1. (local) created branch `newCommits` from `master`.
2. (local) created some commits on the `newCommits` branch.
3. (local+remote) pushed `newCommits` to `origin`.
4. (remote) created Pull Request.
5. (remote) completed pull request which creates an "extra" merge commit.

Until you run `git fetch` (or `git pull` which implicitly does `git fetch`) your local repository does not know anything about those two last remote steps. I assume Github Desktop does `git fetch` behind the scenes in some automatic fashion (this is not uncommon, vscode does something similar), and probably showed you the dialogue at the same time.

How to go forward from here is much more a opinion/what-do-you-want question than a technical question. As TTT already commented, feature branches that are merged into some main branch normally do not have any inherent value after they are merged and can then be deleted. This is by far the most common operation (95%+).

But if you want to continue using the same branch name for a new feature this is possible. Say for instance you are cleaning up log messages, and created a pull request for changes related to *foo* which got merged and now you want to continue cleaning up log messages related to *bar*. For such a use case reusing the branch is perfectly fine (although not super common).

If you want to reuse `newCommits` and fix the "This branch is 1 commit behind the master branch." issue, this is solved by rebasing `newCommits` on top of `master` with the command

```bash
git rebase master newCommits
```

(You should [newer use less than two arguments to rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76119106/23118))

Answer (score 0):

**How you can do it:**

git checkout newCommits
git rebase master

**then try following command:**

git push origin newCommits --force